# Can't get menu to work properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu with sub-menus. The thing is when I hover over a category, the entire div is increased. I want the sub-menus to expand below the div and for the categories to stay inline with eachother.
The website is in Norwegian btw.

```css
html{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
}
#menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color:#B13436;
    margin: 0px;
    top:0;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:#327222;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
#menu ul{
    margin:0px;
}
#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
}
#menu ul li ul{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li ul li{
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li ul li a{
    font-size: 12px;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="./">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="./">Mat</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Oppskrifter</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Handlelister</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="./">Design&kunst </a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Grafisk Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Kunst</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="./">Sex&Samliv </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="./">Sport</a></li>
        <li> <a href="./">Spill</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

Setting the ul li ul  to position absolute will allow it to move without effecting the containing li's. Then by adding a z-index to the dropdown allows it to sit on top of the li below.

Also apply the background (green) to the ul li ul allows the colour to remain continues through the dropdown menu.

Hope this helps.

```css
html{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
}
#menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color:#B13436;
    margin: 0px;
    top:0;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:#327222;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-width: 150px;
/* ADD POSITION RELATIVE TO CONTAIN THE ABSOLUTE POSITIONING ON THE DROPDOWN */
 position: relative;
}
#menu ul{
    margin:0px;
}
#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
 display: block;
}
#menu ul li ul{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: none;
/* BACKGROUND COLOUR AND ABSOLUTE POSITION APPLIED */
    background-color:#327222;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 2;
}
#menu ul li ul li{
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li ul li a{
    font-size: 12px;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
/* REMOVE THE BORDER RADIUS ON THE DROPDOWNS */
#menu li.dropdown:hover,
#menu li.dropdown > ul:hover {
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="./">Home</a> </li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="./">Mat</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Oppskrifter</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Handlelister</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="./">Design&kunst </a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Grafisk Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Kunst</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="./">Sex&Samliv </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="./">Sport</a></li>
        <li> <a href="./">Spill</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, you may want to consider removing the bottom border-radius when the dropdown appears too. I'll update my answer with that too. :o)

Comment: border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; < Adding this to remove the bottom border radius will keep it looking clean and not separated from the menu.

Comment: Thanks :) Actually did that as soon as I saw the result :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute;top: 100%;z-index: 222;left: 0;width: 100%;` to `#menu ul li ul` and `position: relative` to `#menu li`

```css
html{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
}
#menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color:#B13436;
    margin: 0px;
    top:0;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:#327222;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul{
    margin:0px;
}
#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
}
#menu ul li ul{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 222;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu ul li ul li{
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li ul li a{
    font-size: 12px;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nb">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css"/>
<title> Forum </title>
<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3"/>-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="./">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="./">Mat</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Oppskrifter</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Handlelister</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="./">Design&kunst </a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Grafisk Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Kunst</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="./">Sex&Samliv </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="./">Sport</a></li>
        <li> <a href="./">Spill</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```